# Functional programming when to curry

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I am familiar with currying functionality in functional programming.

For language JavaScript.

Yes, I know JS isnt fully functional but it supports currying.

So my 2 questions are:

1) When to use curry and when not. Is there any rule or something.

2) Is there any downside if I autocurry all functions.

For example:

```
const add = (x, y) => x + y
const curryAdd = autoCurry(add) - imagine autoCurry from some library
```

That way there will  be 2 similar functions

But if I start new project and I make all functions single parameter like this:

```
const add = x => y => x + y
```

Everywhere i call add function like this:

```
add(3)(5)
```

instead of this

```
add(3, 5)
```

It only adds 1 char more.

So what are the downsides of make all the project functions curried.

This means file system library, database access, and so on.

Otherwise I will have many "almost duplicated" functions - regular ones and curried once. 
This add complexity because you have to ask yourself should I use curried function or regular and what was the name of the curried function.. and so on.

Thank you

Comment: In Haskell you don't have a choice, all functions are curried. You may want to tag this with JavaScript and remove that part. Also, ramda does not have an `autoCurry` method.

Comment: Thanks, question is edited, i forgot it was just sample code i forgot to change

Comment: You curry the function when it is reasonable to expect that the function will be partially applied.

Comment: This is abstract term, I can expect all functions to be curried if i change my mind to it

Comment: Currying just means abstracting from multi argument functions. So what do you get? Always unary functions. It is much easier to work with them, because they are less complex. It is much easier to combine them, to derive them, to partially apply them. Conclusion: Currying helps to fight complexity and when you use functions and composition significantly, then your code will greatly benefit.

Comment: one downside is the increased overhead of function calls. A function with 3 parameters now results in 3, single-argument function calls. In JavaScript, calling a function has a high cost, so this is not a negligible difference - especially if a curried function is used in loop. ex, `loop (_ => ... call (a) (b) (c))` vs `loop (_ => ... call (a, b, c))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different schools of thought on this, one is not necessarily more "functional" than the others. But first:

Libraries like ramda have a curry function that supports both syntaxes:

```
const add = R.curryN(2, (x, y) => x + y);
add(2)(3); // 5
add(2, 3); // 5
```

So don't get too hung up on the difference.

There's a fairly important idiom that you can't really do while currying in JavaScript: varargs. I mean, you *might* be able to find a (laborious, convoluted) way to make it work, but generally you wouldn't. So if a function can take any number of arguments, it shouldn't be curried.

The next concern is performance.

That's a lot of extra function calls compared to e.g.

```
const add = (x, y) => x + y;
const add3 = add.bind(null, 3);
```

With the first version, every call to `add` pays the price. With this one only the partially applied version does, and it uses a built in (likely faster) to boot.

Finally, a word about contracts:

When you expose functionality to anyone other than yourself (co-workers, customers, open source users), you are making a contract with them that this is the way your function works. If you find that you need to change it later, there are changes that break your existing callers and ones that don't. No one cares about the latter, everyone will curse you for the former.

Going from uncurried to curried (via e.g. ramda) is a *non-breaking change*. Your existing callers will still work. The same is *not* true of the reverse.

Given all that, I would *probably* not curry *any* functions by default unless I'm very very sure that I will be calling them piecemeal every time. Remember, your callers (even if that's you from a different module) can always curry it themselves!

Comment: "*it uses a built in (likely faster)*" - for a long time, `bind` was in fact slower than explicitly creating a closure, probably because of the additional internal checks

Comment: Thank you, the explanation was very good, I knew some of the things but now i realize them :)

Comment: @Bergi I'm sure you're right, but I was comparing to Ramda rather than `x => y => x + y` and IIRC the internals of Ramda it's doing a lot more than just creating a simple closure. I might be misremembering that.

Comment: @user2693928 you're welcome. Frankly in JS and other dynamic languages, I'm not super wild about positional arguments anyways, it's usually a lot more flexible to pass around maps (which won't work with general currying functions).

Comment: I think this is a very good comment and would love it to be a more spread opinion. IMO the destructuring capabilities for objects and arrays should make obvious which solution is more desirable.

Comment: Currying isn't irreversible

Comment: @reify sure, but I don't follow your point.

Comment: What I was trying to imply is that every `curry` function has its `uncurry` counterpart. So there is a Ramda-style `uncurry` function and with this in mind going from curry to uncurry doesn't break anything.

Comment: @reify If I expose a curried function in my API, and people are relying on that behavior (e.g. calling it in some fashion equivalent to `add(3)(2);` and I change my mind and say "nope, no more currying, gotta pass me all the args up front" I just broke my existing callers. The same is not true of changing an normal function to be curried (at least not with using `R.curry`, the simple `x => y => x + y` change *would* also break existing callers).

Answer (score 1):

[Currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) is the transformation of applying a sequence of argument to a function to applying a sequence of functions to individual arguments. In JS this translates to creating a bunch of `Function` which has a significant cost at runtime. However this also has benefits in expressiveness for instance:

```
// the mapping function is
// created at each invocation of add2
const add2 = (coll) => map((x) => x + 2, coll);

// the mapping function is
// created once
const add2 = map((x) => x + 2);
```

This illustrates that

- currying is putting emphasis on the fact that functions are 1st class citizens in your language *and* your domain (you pass around functions *and* values to model your domain).
- it has significant costs in JS if currying happens on a critical path of your app.
- curried functions must be *consistent* in their argument positioning. For instance by convention, transformation functions will take the collection on which to iterate as the last argument.

There is a lot more to say about currying and functional programming. Note that currying is implemented as a transformation of a function in JS, but you can have some of its perks by other means, supporting multi-arity signature is one. In the above example you could have the `map` function defined as:

```
const map = (...args) => {
    switch (args.length) {
        case 1:
            return coll => coll.map(args[0]);
        case 2:
            return args[1].map(args[0]);
        default:
            throw new Error("Wrong arity, expects one or two arguments");
    }
};
```